# How to load an image from a TImageList into TTrayIcon?

Tags: lazarus

Is it possible to load an image from a TImageList into a TTrayIcon at runtime? How? Is this a good idea? Or is there a more preferred method for changing the tray icon's image at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on Windows with Lazarus 0.9.30.4 using an image list composed of translucent png images, it is possible by using a temporary bitmap:

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    ImageList1.GetBitmap(0, Bmp);
    TrayIcon1.Icon.Assign(Bmp);
    TrayIcon1.Show;
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
```

I don't see anything wrong with assigning the icon from an image list image at run-time. Also see example at the component's [wiki page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/TrayIcon) for other possible implementations for assigning the icon at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one liner:

```
ImageList1.GetIcon(0, TrayIcon1.Icon);
```

It copies indexed image list icon to tray icon.